# Evaluate complicated $2d$-integral of the type $\int d^2 x \frac{1}{f(\vec{x})} \arccos(g(\vec{x}))$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following $2$-dimensional integral:

$$I(x_1,x_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} d^2 x_3  \frac{\cos^{-1}\left( \left| \vec{x}_3 \right| / \left| \vec{x}_{13} \right| \right)}{\left| \vec{x}_3 \right|  \sqrt{\vec{x}_{13}^2 -\vec{x}_3^2} \left(\vec{x}_{13}^2-\vec{x}_{23}^2\right)} \tag{1}$$

with $\vec{x} = (x,y)$, $d^2 x_3 = dx_3 dy_3$ and $\vec{x}_{ij} := \vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j$. I tried doing the $y$-integral first with integration by parts, but that gave me an unpleasant $\tanh^{-1}(y')$ and I could not do it.

I also looked in the book "[(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-02462-8.pdf)" by Nahin, but I did not find anything looking like that. It might be useful to note the following identity:

$$\cos^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + i \log \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+i x \right), \tag{2}$$

but again I could not find what to do with that.

I am not sure whether the integral is fully solvable or not. In the case it is not, I would still be interested by either an integration of one variable only, or by a representation in Spencer's functions or something similar.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the integral is divergent at $\left|\vec{x}_3\right| = 0$, so some regularization may be needed.

Comment: Is this integral a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, I've made that explicit now.